# Error en planilla renderizada :UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 24033: invalid start byte

Tags: html, python, flask

estoy diseñando una pequeña app para generar unos documentos de forma automática, tengo las planillas en HTML y estoy usando flask para añadir loops y sustitución de variables, pero me presenta el error que aparece en el titulo, el charset del .html es "**windows-1252**".

Cualquier ayuda sobre como detectar el por que del error, sera bienvenida.

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
from datetime import datetime
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def generador_depositos():
        #fecha_deposito = datetime.today().strftime("%B %d, %Y")
        #envasadora = "La Vega"
        #monto = 23.50
        return render_template("POPULAR.htm")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run(debug=True)
```

No posteo el .html, debido a que es muy extenso.